# Why does sql-mode think -* starts a block comment?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comment, sql-mode

While typing in a SQL mode buffer, I noticed that `-*` starts a block comment. Why?

It happens whenever I type an asterisk/star character (ASCII 42) directly after a simple dash/hyphen/minus character (ASCII 45).

I thought it might be due to `-*- something -*-` buffer hints, but it does not happen in other modes like C++ mode, so it seems to be something else. It does not depend on the SQL dialect I choose.

I tried searching in code but gave up as `-*` gave way too many hits (match zero or more dashes) and `-\*` gave none.

Maybe it's because `-` is the first (and second) character of a comment-start sequence (`--`) and `*` is the second character of a comment-start sequence (`/*`). I used `M-x describe-char` to find this. Following this rationale `*-` should work as a comment-*end* sequence, but it does not.

I only tested GNU Emacs version 26.2 (on Windows).

Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug or typo? I've only used `--` for line comments and `/*` and `*/` for block comments in SQL.

Comment: See the definition of `sql-mode-syntax-table`, though I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @npostavs: this can be fixed with an appropriate dose of `syntax-propertize-function`.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/50398/8706

Comment: I reported this as a minor Emacs bug: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=35646