# Are comment style flags insufficient to separate SQL comments?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comment, sql-mode

I am trying to understand why SQL mode [accepts](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/50375/8706) `-*` as a comment block start.

In `sql.el`, I read:

```
(defvar sql-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; C-style comments /**/ ...
    (modify-syntax-entry ?/ ". 14" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23" table)
    ;; double-dash starts comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- ". 12b" table)
    ;;...
    table) "...")
```

Elisp manual "[Syntax Flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Flags.html)" describes the flags for comment sequences. The digits indeed say `-*` is a two-character comment-start sequence: `1` makes `-` the start and `2` makes `*` the second character.

But `b` is a comment style flag, separating `--` from `/*` and `*/`, which have the default (`a`) style. This sounds like `-*` should *not* count as a comment-start:

> ‘b’ means that ‘-’ as a comment delimiter **belongs to the alternative
>   “b” comment style**.  For a two-character comment starter, this flag is
>   only significant on the second char, and for a 2-character comment
>   ender it is only significant on the first char.

However:

> Each comment delimiter has a style and only matches comment delimiters
>   of the same style.  Thus if a comment starts with the comment-start
>   sequence of style “b”, it will extend until the next matching
>   comment-end sequence of style “b”.

So it turns out that the style flag only regulates which characters will *end* the comment block. Not which characters can be used *together* in a two-character comment sequence!

Am I right that this is why `-*` starts a comment block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These syntax-table settings imply that there are 4 comment-start markers:

- `/*` of style a
- `--` of style b
- `-*` of style a
- `/-` of style b

IIUC two of those are undesired and need to be "weeded out" via `syntax-propertize-function`.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. Indeed `/-` also starts a (line) comment and can actually occur in SQL (`-*` cannot be valid syntax).